# Datasource property not displayed in listview

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a listview in my vb.net 2008 application. I want to attach a datasource to my listview. but the property is not displayed. Is there any problem?? Help. Thanks

Comment: Where is your code? What would you expect anyone to know the issue without looking at the code?

Comment: Place your code @Omkar Pawar so anyone would be able to figure out your question.

Answer (score 2):

ListView does't have a Datasource property(it will not support databinding). You can loop the datatable and load items to ListView